# Get post position in a category

Tags: php, wordpress

here is my issue.

I am currently in a post (so in single.php). I got the only category that this post is in by using:

```
$category = get_the_category()[0];
```

Now, what I would like to be able to know is the current position of that post in that category and I need to be able to retrieve that position without searching through all pages of the category (for performances reasons).

E.g:
Let`s say my post is the 14th most recent post in its category, I want to get that value (14) so that I can then calculate on which category page it would be (knowing how many posts are displayed by page)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of posts/page ahead of time, you can just use SQL to do this.

Lets say you want to do 10 posts/page.

`SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category_id = :categoryID LIMIT 0, 10;`

That will give you the first 10 articles in a given category. If you see the articles for page two, you just modify the `LIMIT`

Comment: I thought of multiple ways to do it with searching through pages as you suggested. I was more wondering if there were a more direct way that would cost the same time when we call it for a new or an old post.

Comment: using PHP to do something will ALWAYS take more time than doing it in SQL.

Comment: The solution could be using SQL as well. All I am saying is that I am looking for a one shoot PHP or SQL; not searching through multiple calls as you are suggesting

Comment: Can you explain why you need to know where a given article is in a category? Something tells me that there may be other issues here.

Comment: To be able to know on which category`s page it would be displayed (as I put in my Eg.). The ultimate goal being to see the current post (since in single.php) and a list of all the other posts that are on the same category page.

Comment: Then just pass a variable through get that tells it what page it was on?

Comment: I can`t pass that kind of parameters since the URL would change with time. So if today it is associated with page 2 and I bookmark it, in the future, it would slip to page 5 and the post would look wrong since it would display the page 2 that doesn`t contain the current post

Comment: Then have a page that displays articles, and a page that lists them. It can still be one file.

Comment: I cannot change the requirement. The requirement is to show the current post and the posts in the same page of the same category. I cannot split it in two separate pages; else that would just be category.php and single.php and that would be so much simpler :P

Comment: Just saying, with the growing number of posts that are made, the speed of the site is SERIOUSLY going to degrade. That is not a realistic requirement.

Comment: If I have to search through pages until I find the one containing the current post, I know that would degrade. That`s why I asked my question to know how to retrieve the post`s offset in one shoot.

Comment: No, if you have to loop over thousands, potentially millions of posts to find which page a post should be on, it will significantly slow down the speed of your site. It could take minutes to load a single article if it was one of the first articles written. That is not a realistic requirement because of speed.

Comment: That`s what I just said.
Me: "If I have to search through pages until I find the one..."
You: "if you have to loop over thousands"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37433/discussion-between-justin-wood-and-simon-levesque)